# Socket.io respond to sender

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

What I'm trying to do is have socket respond to the sender ONLY. What I'm currently doing: 
When user visit webpage I included js so he connects on server (on all webpages) but i'm not sure here when user reload page or just switch pages will he be reconnected every time or connection stays the same ? 
Now I'm sending data to my node.js app that do something with it but in case of error/success How can I emit to specific client that send data (now i emit data for every user that is connected)

Comment: You should add enough source code to describe the question.

Comment: To get an answer that is likely to be quick and accurate and not a guess, you need to include the relevant portion of your code in your question.  Questions about specific code should include the relevant code you have - always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call emit on the socket object :

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('event', () => {
    socket.emit('otherEvent', { data : ... });
  });
});
```